# C# Sqlite: Attempt to write a readonly database

Tags: c#, .net, database, sqlite

I have read many posts about this issue: "Attempt to write a readonly database". I have tried their solutions and the problem persists. What baffles me is that the error occurs seemingly sporadically. It doesn't happen once and happens later. I restart Visual Studio 2015 and the problem goes away, and it comes back after a few database transactions. Does anyone have any idea why this might be happening?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: if not reproducible nobody can help

Comment: Is it possible that the sqlite "driver" leaves the/some file(s) in a locked state by not closing a handle and thus giving you the readonly error (driver bug)? Does it happen with a specific DB/table/query only?

Comment: I have figured out 'a' solution. I have connection pooling set to true. Once I set it false, the error goes away. I know this isn't a perfect solution but it works for now since my application isn't huge.